# jQuery on change fires twice on input file elements

Tags: jquery, file, events, input, onchange

I have trouble with 2 file inputs:

```
<span class="btn btn-info btn-file" id="a">
    Selecteer afbeeldingen

    <input accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png" multiple="multiple" id="btn-file-images" name="media[]" type="file">
</span>

<span class="btn btn-info btn-file" id="b">
    Selecteer media
    <input accept=".csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/msword,application/pdf,application/x-rar-compressed,application/zip,image/vnd.adobe.photoshop,application/illustrator" multiple="multiple" id="btn-file-media" name="media[]" type="file">
</span>
```

With jQuery I put an eventlistener on .btn-file input

```
var uploadTab = $('#upload')
, tabForms = $('.tab-pane form', uploadTab)
, fileInputHandler = function fileInputHandler () {
    var input = $(this)
      , numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1
      , label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');

     handleFiles(this, this.files);
}

tabForms.on('change', '.btn-file input', fileInputHandler);
```

The trouble is that with thise 2 .btn-file classes on one page it fires the function twice. I've tried to put the event on ID's "a" and "b" separately but no luck. When I comment out one of the inputs it works fine, it fires once.

I've also changed the name attribute from one of them but no luck either.

There is also another topic on stackoverflow that was worth trying because I was desperate but that didn't work either.

[jQuery change event fired twice when giving focus to another control inside the change callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229754/jquery-change-event-fired-twice-when-giving-focus-to-another-control-inside-the)

Comment: Never mind, It appears the javascript file is included twice, still weird the double event handling only happends multiple times when there are multiple instances of an element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the javascript file is included twice